# Firebase Github Deploy Cannot Parse travis.yml

Tags: firebase, github, travis-ci

I am trying to follow this tutorial to deploy to firebase from github using travis CI. https://medium.com/@cpavnn/deploy-to-firebase-hosting-from-github-3772fed05e72

For my `.travis.yml` file I used:

```yaml
language: node_js

node_js:
 — "7"

before_script:
 — npm install -g firebase-tools

script:
 — echo "Deploy!!"

after_success:
 — firebase deploy — project projectId — token $FIREBASE_TOKEN.`
```

But every time I deploy I get this error:

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Your after success seems suspicious, does it really expect those hyphens?

Comment: I've tried versions with the hyphens directly next to the words and it still does not new. I am new the YAML and Travis. Do you have a version that you think would work?

Comment: I'd suggest two things: 1. Extract your commands and test them locally; and 2. Quote out anything that breaks YAML parsing. You can find validators online to make sure it's syntactically valid.

Comment: Can you link me to an online one? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try searching for one and see how it goes.

Comment: I have and they are all deprecated.

Comment: In addition to the above there is a `\`` at the end of your `after_success` hook. Also the deploy command should be `firebase deploy --project projectId --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN` (Double hyphens no space)

Comment: Paste your YAML in https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator It appears you could be using some unicode non breaking space character.

Comment: @sketchthat the ` is from the person who edited my post or how I pasted it in, it's not that way in the github code. Even with your suggested changes it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `node_js: 7` on the one line without quotes.

I haven't tested this, but this is a format I usually use.

```yaml
language: node_js

node_js: 7

before_script:
- npm install -g firebase-tools

script:
- firebase deploy --project projectId --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

Don't forget to add your secret `FIREBASE_TOKEN` into Travis CI and in addition replace `projectId` to your Firebase project id.

The Medium article your outlined looks to have invalid characters in the YAML. Try typing it out instead of a copy & paste.